# Printing from non-domain computers

Tags: authentication, printing

I have a domain print-server with some network printers configured (TCP/IP ports). I need to be able to print from non-domain computers. There is a requirement that all users have this printer added (preferably as default).

Normally I'd add a printer as a local printer, but I'm not sure how I can use a service account to map a printer in this scenario.

I had a play around with prnmngr.vbs but with no luck. I get an error stating that *"User credentials cannot be used for local connections"*

In this scenario, it is not acceptable to print *directly* to the printers.

Comment: You may be able to use the Internet Printing Role on the server and Internet Printing Client on the endpoints.  See this answer: http://serverfault.com/a/730891/20701

Comment: I'm guessing this is something to do with Microsoft Windows? You should probably explain what operating systems are involved here.